# Testflight beta testers won't get build mails?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I used to send builds from testflight using Apple's beta testflight. From 1 week my testers won't get emails regarding new build. They have checked in testflight app also but they can't find the builds. Can somebody help me?

Note: I have submitted the app to apple for testflight. It was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically we got all build mails. There may be issue in apple server or something else.